# Application does not work on device but work on genymotion emulator

Tags: android

I have created a projected related to android database .

It work fine on GENYMOTION  emulator only.
But when i install this on mobile device which is

android version is 5.0 so then it showed the error is" 0 requested, with a size of 0".
It also not work on android emultor.

it just only work on genymotion emulator.

```
 login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        usernamee=user.getText().toString();
        userpass=pasword.getText().toString();
        DatabaseOperations DOP=new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
        Cursor CR=DOP.getInformation(DOP);
        CR.moveToFirst();
        boolean loginstatus=false;
        String NAME="";

        if(user.getText().toString().trim().length()==0||
                   pasword.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fields are empty Please enter

       user name and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
        }
        else{

        try{
        do{

            if(usernamee.equals(CR.getString(0))&& 

           (userpass.equals(CR.getString(1))))  
            {


                loginstatus=true;
                NAME=CR.getString(0);
            }


        }
        while(CR.moveToNext());


        if(loginstatus)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Log in Successed", 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else

        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Log in failed invalid user 
         name OR password or no record found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
        }


        }
        }
```

When i click the above log in  button it work fine on only on genymotion emulator.
But when i press this log in button in mobile device in which the app is installed.
It does not work showed the error is index 0 requested with size of 0.
and on android emulator also showed this error.

the log cat is

```
      08-29 13:29:35.978: I/Choreographer(1339): Skipped 93 frames!  The 
      application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 
      08-29 13:29:36.956: I/Choreographer(1339): Skipped 43 frames!  The 
     application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
     08-29 13:29:37.498: I/Choreographer(1339): Skipped 43 frames!  The  
     application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
      08-29 13:29:53.498: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1339): KeyEvent:
     ACTION_UP but key was not down.
     08-29 13:29:53.498: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1339):   in 
    android.widget.EditText{4178dba0 VFED..CL .F....I. 0,127-320,167  
     #7f080009 app:id/register_paswd}
   08-29 13:29:53.498: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1339):   in   
   android.widget.EditText{4178dba0 VFED..CL .F....I. 0,127-320,167 
  #7f080009 app:id/register_paswd}
    08-29 13:29:53.498: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1339):   0: sent at   
  17891468000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB,    
  scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=17891468, 
    downTime=17891295, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
     08-29 13:29:53.498: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1339):   0: sent at    
    17891468000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, 
    scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=17891468, 
  downTime=17891295, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
   08-29 13:29:59.698: W/dalvikvm(1339): threadid=1: thread exiting with 
  uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)


 08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main


 08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339): 

 android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a 

  size of 0


 08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):    at 

 android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)


 08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339

  08-29 13:29:59.718:
```

ndowedCursor.java:50)
08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at com.example.student_record.Setting$2.onClick(Setting.java:149)
08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

```
   08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):  at 

   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

   08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):  at
```

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

```
   08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):  at 
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

 08-29 13:29:59.718: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):    at     
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please post the logcat lines related to this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor is not reporting any data and crashing when you call .moveToFirst(). You should check if this is not null before trying to use the cursor.

Comment: But why it wokr on emulator not on device

Comment: Include the code for creating your database etc and we might be able to help :-)